# Extjs 5 store.load()

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs5

I have a simple (`user_data`) store. I load this store:

```
user_data_store.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(g, records, operation, success) {
         console.log(g);
         var login_name = ???
    },
});
```

This is a simple json:

```
[{
   "login_id" : "1",
   "login_name" : "test",
   "login_email" : "test@test.com",
   "login_mobile" : "11111111"
 }]
```

But I don't know how get login_name? (test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
user_data_store.load({
       scope: this,
       callback: function(records, operation, success) {
           console.log(records[0].get('login_name'));
       },
});
```

Comment: Sorry. This is not working. Uncaught TypeError: records.getAt is not a function

Comment: sorry.. try with records[0].get('login_name'), I've updated my answer.
Also, If this doesn't work.. place the contents of console.log(records) in your question

Comment: Guilherme Lopes: Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, usually when you have an ExtJS object that has a data property, you can use a getter/setter with it. So record[0].get('login_name') or record[0].set('login_name', 'sencha');

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
store.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // the operation object
        // contains all of the details of the load operation
        console.log(records[0].login_name);
    }
});
```

refer [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load)

Comment: Sorry. This is not working. My console.log(records); :                                  [g]                                                                                                                    0: g
data: Object
id: "extModel493-1"
login_email: "test@test.com"                                                               login_id: "1"
login_mobile: "11111111"
login_name: "test"

Comment: console.log(g); => undefined

Comment: try logging  `arguments` & check  where you are getting actual records

Comment: Looks like you are setting wrong number of parameters, as per docs there are only 3 params available namely `records, operation, success`

Comment: MMT: Thanks for your help!